# Configure EF DAO to return detached entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible (with attributes or something) to configure DAO methods to return detached objects? I am keen to do this, because I want to make sure that the DAO pre-fetches any fields and relationships that might be required by downstream code on return from the DAO. If the entities are detached, then an exception will be thrown and we can identity the issue easily. With lazy resolution of relationships, you potentially get multiple additional requests to the DB without realising it.

For example, let's say I have a DAO class:

```
public class TestDao
{
    private readonly MyContext _db;

    public TestDao(MyContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public List<Group> AllGroups()
    {
        return _db.Groups.ToList();    
    }
}
```

And then say that I have a client of the Dao:

```
public void TestGetAllGroups()
{
    var groups = _testDao.AllGroups();

    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        var x = group.Memberships;    
        Console.WriteLine( group.id + ":" + x.Count );
    }    
}
```

This code works, but each iteration in the test harness causes a new hit to the DB because the DB hasn't pre-fetched (included) the Memberships relationship.

I'm looking for the best way to get this code to throw an exception, saying that group.Memberships is null or something. If the Group instances were detached upon exit from `TestDao.AllGroups()`, then this would do the trick, and alert us to the fact that the DAO needs to include the Memberships before returning from the `AllGroups()` method

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can disable Lazy Loading of relationships. In my Context class:

```
 public partial class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        static MyContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        }

        public MyContext() : this("Name=MyContext")
        {
        }

        public MyContext(string name): base(name)
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
        ...
}
```

However, in addition to this, I need to make sure that the EF entity constructor doesn't create empty lists for the one-to-many relations. These seem to get added by default with the schema-first entity code generation tool:

```
public partial class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        //Remove this line!
        //this.Memberships = new List<Membership>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }

}
```

Now, my test harness will throw a NPE unless I put a .Include into the Dao to include Memberships

Comment: Removing the constructors for the one-to-many relations does have the disadvantage that you have to manually construct the list if you want to create a new entity and create new relations for that entity...